# Secure way to realloc

Tags: c

I'm writing a C library which needs to often move around various sensitive data. I want to have benefits of realloc (extending allocated block instead copying when memory is available) while having some way to erase content of old block if copying is necessary.

Is there some lightweight implementation of malloc/realloc/free which could be used for mingw-gcc or some other trick to it, or I must overallocate and just allocate-and-copy without relying on realloc?

Comment: I guess in most cases, reallocating a block to a larger size would result in the old block being copied anyway, so you might as well do it manually with malloc and free rather than relying on some 3rd party "secure" realloc implementation.

Comment: if you want to have some way to erase the content of the old block why won't you save a pointer to it?

Comment: @CisForCookies The old pointer would no longer be valid after a realloc (unless it is the same as the new pointer).

Comment: @PSkocik Wouldn't `mremap` rely on the system erasing the old memory block at a time of its choosing (if it results in the memory being moved)?

Comment: @IanAbbott A first mmap will always give zeroed memory on a security-minded system. Then, once `mlocked`, the memory is yours until you `munmap` it (at which point you  had better make sure zeroed it first).

Comment: you can implement your allocator as a balanced tree.  using a balanced tree you can implement all these functions in logarithmic time.  watch garbage collector algorithms for details.

Comment: @PSkocik Okay, thanks. So `MREMAP_MAYMOVE` wouldn't actually make a copy, it would just remap the currently mapped physical memory pages to a region of virtual address space with more room. I think I understand now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Linux, [`mmap`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) the block, [`mlock`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html) it, and then do [`mremap`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mremap.2.html) instead of using `realloc`.

Protecting against hidden copies isn't enough. You also need to make sure the memory never ever gets swapped to disk before you get a chance to zero it.

Comment: Aren't we glad that we have practically infinite virtual memory?

Comment: Also for protection against swapping, one can pin the pages(for the entire duration), but assuming you trust the OS.